# Solving differential equation with periodic variable (poincare section)

Tags: differential-equations, periodic-function

I'm trying to make a Poincare section using the code here:

```
Vvbc[x_, t_, c_] := Vd E^(-(x - c - L/2)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))
trianglewave = L/T (Abs[Mod[t - T/4, T] - T/2] - T/4);
Vdir[x_] := -D[Vvbc[x, t, c[t]], x] /. {c[t] -> trianglewave, 
c'[t] -> DtwaveDt};
data = Table[Block[{\[Sigma] = 1/Sqrt[2], Vd = -10, L = 16, T = 0.05}, 
 Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == Vdir[x[t]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == xp0, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, T] == 0, Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 
    1000 T}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]][[-1, 1]], {xp0, -5, 5, 
0.05}];
```

which produces a valid section. However, I want to solve this equation with a periodic `x(t)` i.e $mod(x,L)=0$. I've tried manually setting `Mod[x[t],L]==0`, but this throws up an "overdetermined" error. Using `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` would allow me to make `x[t]` periodic in `t`, but I want to make `x` itself periodic in `L`.

Comment: So you have an ODE of the form $x'' +x' =f(x,t)$, with two initial conditions, right? If you add an equation, your system becomes overdetermined, hence the error. Said differently, if you specify values for `Vd, L, T, sigma`, generically, there is no periodic solution. You should probably relax (at least) one of the values.

Comment: I have an ODE of the form $ x''(t) = f( x(t)) $, with initial conditions in $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$. I know why it's throwing up the overdetermined error, but I'm not trying to add another equation, I'm trying to solve the equation specifying a periodic variable.

Comment: OK so let's say you want to find the periodic solutions to $x''(t) = 1$ with $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=1$. What periodic solution(s) would you expect?

Comment: Here we get a quadratic trajectory $ x(t) = \frac{1}{2} t^2 + t +1 $. Now I want that when $x(t)$ reaches the value $L$, it will "wrap around" back to the value 0. i.e, the full solution would be $ x_{periodic}(t) = mod( \frac{1}{2} t^2 +t +1, L)$. 

This is easy to achieve when I have an analytic solution for the trajectory, but not as trivial when I want to solve the equation numerically.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $x_\mathrm{periodic}$ is not actually periodic, because there is no $T$ such that $\forall t,\ x(t+T)=x(t)$. Why don't you solve the ODE on $[0,L]$, and then just extend it to $\mathbb{R}$ using the modulo?

Comment: I don't want it to be periodic in time, I want it to be periodic in space. If you plot $ x'(t) $ vs $ x(t)$ then as the trajectory goes off the edge of $[0,L)$, it should wrap around and come back to 0 (or L). 

I'm trying to solve the ODE on $[0,L)$ with this periodic condition, but I don't know how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: So you want to solve the ODE on a circle?

Comment: As I wrote in my last comment, solve on $[0,L)$ (`xsol`), then define `x` by something like `x[t_] = Mod[xsol[t], L]`, if that is what you want. But you should clarify your question: _"a periodic x(t) i.e mod(x,L)=0"_ is incorrect, that's not the definition of a periodic function, and _"periodic variable"_ does not mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got comments right, solving the Cauchy problem for `x''[t]==f[Mod[x[t],L]]` and then putting `y[t_]=Mod[x[t],L]` gives that you want.

Comment: Stumbled across this by accident myself. This does exactly what I want. Thanks!